# Raspberry PI Sense Hat Joystick triggering event on reset

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspberry-pi2

I have a simple python program that uses the sense hats joystick as inputs, which calls reads from various sensors on the hat and returns their values to the 8x8 LED display. The program works but there is only one problem, it returns each show_message() twice. Once on the initial press and again when the joystick 'resets'. I know this because if I hold up for example, it will display the temperature, then when i release it, it shows it again.

Can anyone help me to only show the messages once? The pygame events seem to tie the joystick to the arrow keys, and looking through the pygame documentation I dont see any mention of reset.

Here is my code:

```
from sense_hat import AstroPi
import time
import datetime
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

ap = AstroPi()
ap.clear()

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))


pressure = 'P: ' + str(int(ap.get_pressure()))
temp =  'T: ' + str(int(ap.get_temperature_from_pressure()))
humidity = 'H: ' + str(int(ap.get_humidity()))
blah = 'blah!'

def handle_event(event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ap.show_message(pressure)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ap.show_message(temp)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ap.show_message(humidity)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ap.show_message(blah)       


running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            handle_event(event)
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            handle_event(event)
        if event.type == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have limited responses here, because not everyone owns the sensor hat, (including me) but I'll take a stab at it. Some of the sensors I do own have problems with successive reads happening too quickly. Usually a delay between readings solves the issue. I can't test it, but it's a good starting point. Try the following:

```
import time
# after each handle_event() call in the second loop try adding a delay such as
handle.event(event)
time.sleep(1)
```

If this happens to solve the issue, try reducing the sleep time to a much smaller number (.01) or until the problem resurfaces. If that doesn't help we can keep digging.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris! The only problem with this is that it isnt an issue where its a succesive read happening to quickly. Its that when the joystick goes up it sends the signal for up, and when it 'resets' aka clicks back into neutral position it sends the up signal again. If i just quickly pres up and release, it runs my up method twice. if i press and hold up, it will run it once, then whenever i release the joystick it runs it again. So a sleep will just further delay the reset method call, but wont bypass it.  Maybe i could write a method that ignores every other click

Answer (score 0):

I got a Pi & SenseHat for Christmas. I tried your program and found if I delete one of the first two `if` statements.

```
(if event.type == KEYDOWN:) or ( if event.type == KEYUP:)
```

It will work one time only.  I known I am a year late, but I hope this helps.

Your problem helped me to learn more about the SenseHat joystick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried to move a red square around the sensor. When I pressed the right or left direction on the joystick it went two squares. To fix this just create an AND statement with both event.direction and event.action

```
if event.direction == 'right' and event.action == 'pressed':
```

So it only executes when the joystick is initially pressed